# VideoJS Chromecast plays live stream from the wrong place

Tags: casting, chromecast, video.js, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I'm using latest Video.js and Chromecast plugin I found working in some videos. My problem is that some streams with long (5 hours) buffer start to play from start of the track even it should start from the end. Is it possible configure Chromecast script somehow to start streaming close the end? I'm using both techniques HLS and DASH with vjs plugins.

I'm using this plugin for Chromecast
https://github.com/ricksancho/videojs-chromecast

```
<video id=video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay preload="auto" controls></video>

<script>
var player = videojs('video');
player.ready(function() {
  this.hotkeys({
    volumeStep: 0.1,
    seekStep: 5,
    enableModifiersForNumbers: false
  });
  player.src({
    src: dada,
    type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
  });
   player.chromecast();
  player.play();
});
</script>
```